# Firebase Cross Service Security Rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, firebase-security, firebase-tools

I am trying to implement a Firestore check in my Storage rules following:

https://firebase.blog/posts/2022/09/announcing-cross-service-security-rules

The `exists` function works fine but I keep getting errors on `get`. I am using the **emulators** and running firebase-tools 11.17.0

This returns true or false correctly:

```js
function found(datasetId) {
    return firestore.exists(/databases/(default)/documents/datasets/$(datasetId))
}
```

This fails every time:

```js
function shared(datasetId) {
    return firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/datasets/$(datasetId)).data.meta.privacy == 'public';
}
```

An error shows up in emulators on initial load and with every request:

```js
com.google.firebase.rules.runtime.common.EvaluationException: Error: /home/max/Projects/test/websites/namespace/test-web/storage.rules line [10], column [24]. Service call error. Function: [firestore.get], Argument: [path_value {
  segments {
    simple: "databases"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "(default)"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "documents"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "datasets"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "13ypyc346atp3gqywoqB"
  }
}
].
```

The actual rule is very simple, and works fine if I remove the shared function:

```js
allow read: if found(datasetId) && shared(datasetId)
```

Comment: This seems to be a Firebase bug that occurs if any field in the requested Firestore document contains null.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5251

Comment: As mentioned in the thread you shared in above comment, Have you deleted the line `deletedAt: null`? Are you still getting exception?

Comment: @RoopaM Yes removing null works. But removing these fields breaks the index so I can no longer query correctly so its not a solution.

Comment: seems like currently there are no other workarounds for this. please add your concern on the github issue shared and follow that thread for further updates.

Comment: A fix has been merged into master, should be included in the next release.

Comment: Great to hear @KalenMichael. Can you post that as an answer one the fix lands in a release too? That makes it more likely others will learn about the fix too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was bug in firebase-tools that was fixed in v11.19.0

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v11.19.0

> Fixed bug with Cross-Service Rules integration for Firestore documents containing nulls