# Error using firestore.get from firebase storage security rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I'm trying to create a firebase storage security rule that queries a data saved in firestore, the idea is to allow or block the ability to upload an image to storage depending on a property stored in firestore. Following the documentation page [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/rules-conditions#enhance_with_firestore) and the firebase announcement [announcing-cross-service-security-rules](https://firebase.blog/posts/2022/09/announcing-cross-service-security-rules), I wrote the following rule:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /images/{userId}/{image} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId
        && request.resource.size < 10 * 1024 * 1024 // max size 10MB
        && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*')
        && firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/data_users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.tokens > 0;
    }
  }
}
```

This throws the following error:

```
com.google.firebase.rules.runtime.common.EvaluationException: Error: /home/miuser/Documents/code/test_project/storage.rules line [9], column [22]. Service call error. Function: [firestore.get], Argument: [path_value {
  segments {
    simple: "databases"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "(default)"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "documents"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "data_users"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "9eP2MrjhoQ2CR5w9GcW31hx6uZfF"
  }
}
].
```

When I remove the line that contains firestore.get everything works correctly, I have exhaustively verified the path and it is correct, I have even done tests changing that line to something simpler like: `&& firestore.exist(/databases/(default)/documents/data_users)` but I get similar error.

I am using the firebase emulators with Ubuntu 22.04, my firebase-tools version is 12.4.3. I really appreciate your help in advance, I'm really stuck on this.

Comment: Have a look at this github [thread](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5251) and stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75076357/firestore-get-function-not-working-in-cloud-storage-security-rules) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74742346/firebase-cross-service-security-rules)